# Vertical 3dCarousel animation in android?

Tags: android, animation, carousel

How i can achieve this animation in android, here below is the link which i have tried to modify it but there is no output like below image.

[image]

http://horribile.blogspot.in/2011/11/android-3d-carousel.html

https://github.com/rameshkec85/Android-VerticalCarousel

i have modify below function for vertical animation as below.

```
private void Calculate3DPosition(CarouselItem child, int diameter,
            float angleOffset) {

    angleOffset = angleOffset * (float) (Math.PI / 180.0f);
    float x = 0.0f;
    float y = (float) (diameter / 2 * Math.sin(angleOffset)) + diameter / 2 - child.getWidth() / 2;
    float z = diameter / 2 * (1.0f - (float) Math.cos(angleOffset));                 

    child.setItemX(x);
    child.setItemZ(z);
    child.setItemY(y);
    }
```

when i implement this as a result, animation is not work properly and also image is not display in center correctly.

does any body have implement this animation correctly, Please send me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i have achieved this animation.

Below is the link for horizontal carousel animation which is most popular.

[Androd 3d carousel animation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel)

Now, here is the changes to achieve vertical carousel animation from above animation.

**Carousel.java**

1. **onFling** : Change **velocityX** To **velocityY**
2. **onScroll :** Change   trackMotionScroll(/* -1 * */ (int) distanceX); **To**   trackMotionScroll(/* -1 * */ (int) distanceY);
3. **scrollIntoSlots :** change "if (angle != 0.0f)" **to** "if (Math.abs(angle) > 4)"
4. **Calculate3DPosition :**

   angleOffset = angleOffset * (float) (Math.PI / 180.0f);

   ```
       float x = (screenWidth - child.getWidth())/2;       
       float y = (float) (diameter / 2 * Math.sin(angleOffset)) + diameter / 2 - child.getWidth() / 2;
       float z = diameter*2 * (1.0f - (float) Math.cos(angleOffset));

       child.setItemX(x);
       child.setItemZ(z);
       child.setItemY(y-(screenHeight - child.getHeight())/2);
   ```

Enjoy carousel animation.

Comment: Hello. I am working on horizontal 3d carousel, I stuck with one issue. how to reduce scroll speed ?

Comment: you have to track with trackMotionScroll speed, just change in trackMotionScroll value and change in on fling method.

Comment: Hi @Hasmukh what is `screenWidth` it's a device screen width or angleoffset? And what about `angleOffset = angleOffset * (float) (Math.PI / 180.0f);` I have to add this also or not?

Comment: yes, it is device width, and also need to add angleOffset = angleOffset * (float) (Math.PI / 180.0f); this should be remain as it is.

Comment: Hello @Hasmukh i am adding 100 images then problem in animation ...
animation are not work proper ... please help me ....

Answer (score 2):

First of all, try setting:

```
float x = child.getWidth() / 2;
```

That should solve the image not being centered problem.
The y & z look ok, but maybe try changing the y placement to take into account the view's height instead of it's width?:

```
float y = (float) (diameter / 2 * Math.sin(angleOffset)) + diameter / 2 - child.getHeight() / 2;
```

Not sure if this'll work since I didn't set the project up, but I hope it'll get you closer at least :)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this is not helping much.